# Writing a search field script that returns data from an XML file

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to write a script that loops through an xml file. with the code provided below, It returns the alerts but doesnt show information when a proper value is entered in the search field. However, when I remove the error checks and leave the last if statement, it runs and shows the proper values entered in the form.

```
function searchAStylist() {
        var StylistListXML = loadXML("StylistList.xml");
        var StylistListXML_root = StylistListXML.documentElement;
        var stylistInfo_array = StylistListXML_root.getElementsByTagName('stylistInfo');
        storedResults = new Array;
        var stlyist_ul = document.getElementById("stylist");
        var search_field_div_test = " ?=(?:.*?[A-Za-z]){2}";

        var search_field_div = document.getElementById("search_field").value.toLowerCase().split(/[ ,]+/).join(' ');
        //console.debug(parseName + " test");
        for (var i = 0 ; i < stylistInfo_array.length; i++) {

            var nameElement = stylistInfo_array[i].getElementsByTagName('Name')[0];

            var li_element = document.createElement('li');
            var h2_element = document.createElement('h2');
            var h4_element = document.createElement('h4');
            var h42_element = document.createElement('h5');

            var name_text = nameElement.firstChild.nodeValue.replace(/,/g, ' ');
            var parseName = $.trim(name_text).replace(/,/g, ' ');
            var firstName = parseName.split(' ').slice(-1).join(' ');
            var lastName = parseName.split(' ').slice(0, -1).join(' ');
            var fullName = firstName + " " + lastName;


            h2_element.appendChild(document.createTextNode(fullName));
            li_element.appendChild(h2_element);

            h4_element.appendChild(document.createTextNode(combinedPostalCode.toUpperCase()));
            li_element.appendChild(h4_element);

            h42_element.appendChild(document.createTextNode(country_text.toUpperCase()));
            li_element.appendChild(h42_element);

            if (search_field_div == null || search_field_div == '') {
                alert("Please enter a Stylist name(First/Last or Full name), or Postal Code or City");
                return false;
            }else if(!(fullName.toLowerCase().indexOf(search_field_div) != -1)){
                alert("No Stylist found with that criteria");
                break;
            }

            if (fullName.toLowerCase().indexOf(search_field_div) != -1) {
                console.debug(parseName);
                stlyist_ul.appendChild(li_element);
            }
        }//END OF FOR LOOP

    }//END OF FUNCTION
```

Answer (score 0):

This break statement here causes the loop to break as soon as first non-matching record is encountered, which in most of the cases may be the first iteration

```
else if(!(fullName.toLowerCase().indexOf(search_field_div) != -1)){
    alert("No Stylist found with that criteria");
    break;
}
```

To skip the current iteration and move to the next, `continue` statement is used